# Как сделать на питоне аналог JS CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString()?

Tags: javascript, python

Есть функция на ЯваСкрипте

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), d, {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString()
```

На выходе выдает разные значения, например, 
"{"ct":"WRGouUKxcFHLSGReAWBNLg==","iv":"d32fe4b7635f0290e8a99114c9d01fe8","s":"e571997ee26f1c47"}"

Как мне сделать то же самое на python?

upd:
Перепробовал десятки различных комбинаций и до сих пор мне не удалось добиться точно такого же результата, что получает функция CryptoJS.AES.encrypt. Как я понимаю, по умолчанию, она использует AES.MODE_ECB шифрование и паддинг по принципу pkcs7

Например, возьмем такие входные данные для JS:

```
var data = 'abc';
var d = 'zs0aneq7neem';
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), d, {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString();
```

получим результат "{"ct":"0PhO/O4UezpeOK9+2Bj7Lg==","iv":"ec0b83442cdb700036a7ce7b5248df28","s":"0c53a0dd5a3ccdc3"}"

по идее для питона то же самое должно получиться в следующих строках

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64, pkcs7
pad_text = pkcs7.PKCS7Encoder().encode('abc')
IV = 'ec0b83442cdb700036a7ce7b5248df28'
pad_key = pkcs7.PKCS7Encoder().encode('zs0aneq7neem')
aes = AES.new(pad_key, AES.MODE_ECB, IV)
res = base64.b64encode(aes.encrypt(pad_text))
```

но результат в res другой: 'Pp3wAckR5aFeAVipqVpFhw=='

возможно вместо pad_key надо использовать фактическую секретную фразу, т.е. "0c53a0dd5a3ccdc3", но и в этом случае мы получаем 'LhVrW1duY+0Jh1ucE/FEsg==', что отличается от результата яваскрипт.

Answer (score 0):

На питоне можно отлично шифровать:
AES:
[AES 256  English Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256)

[AES 128  Habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/212235/)

RSA Module:
https://pypi.org/project/rsa/

PyCrypto Module:
https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/

Cryptography module:https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/

Легкое гуглиние даст кучу всего по шифрованию,  криптологии и криптоанализу на питоне.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но пока топчусь на том же месте, о чем подробнее написал в upd вопроса.